# Why can't I plot a graphic using matplotlib in interactive mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using python 3.8.0 with matplotlib 2.2.4

I would like to use the interactive mode but I can't even plot a simple graphic.

The folowing code is creating an empty window.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

import time

plt.ion()

plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])

plt.show()

time.sleep(3)
```